# Automate actions in the browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, selenium, firefox-addon

So I work for a company where I always have to go through 5 webpages before I start debugging the issue.

It's ALWAYS the same.

1. On the first page i always click the same link
2. On the second page I always click the same link
3. On the third page, I always type a parameter on the same text box
4. On the fourth page, I always click the same link

Would the best way to automate this be via a google-chrome or mozzila-firefox plugin? If not, what would be the best approach to automate this task so that I don't waste 5 minutes every hour?

Thank you for your time!
Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)? It cam be used to do all sorts of stuff, from a text expander to windows management, but it can also simply output keystrokes. I use it do something kind of like what you want to do.

You can make a shortcut key that could output the correct number of TABs, ENTERs, and the parameter you have to type in the box. The only problem is that if the website changes at all, you might have to change your script.

Something like this:

```
SetCapsLockState, alwaysoff
CAPSLOCK & Numpad1::
send {TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}
Sleep, 5000
send {TAB}{TAB}{TAB}parameter{ENTER}
return
```

Also, XKCD for everything: [Is It Worth The Time?](http://xkcd.com/1205/)

Comment: +1 for the XKCD comic, haha. This tool looks pretty sick and I'll give it a try and let you know! Thank you for the recommendation! :0)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/) add-on for Firefox, you could automate this process in 1 minute by recording a macro.  Every time you need to debug simply play the macro.  Here is some sample code that searches for the add-on via google.

```
URL GOTO=www.google.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:gbqf ATTR=ID:gbqfq CONTENT=imacros<SP>for<SP>firefox
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:gbqf ATTR=ID:gbqfb
TAG POS=1 TYPE=EM ATTR=TXT:iMacros<SP>for<SP>Firefox
```

This code was generated with the iMacros recording feature.

Comment: Seems interesting! Thank you, I'll check it out as well! :0)